# Python convert lines string to polygon if closed

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I have a series of contour linestrings some are closed and some are not. The linestring values are between -1 and 1. I am trying to create polygons from the linestrings if they close and keep the value. I have asked this question similar question before and haven't been able to find a solution. because the polylines are contours, there will be donut polygons. The code below will generate the correct polygons, but cannot get the 'ExtraData' value into the newly created polygons.

```
polylines = fiona.open(input_file)
geom = [x['geometry'] for x in polylines]
coords = [x['coordinates']for x in geom[:-1]]

# {{'ExtraData': 'float'}} should be carried over from the polyline

schema =  {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'id': 'int'}}
with fiona.open(output_file, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as c:
    for poly_id,polygon in enumerate(polygonize(coords)):
        c.write({
            'geometry': mapping(polygon),
            'properties': {'id': poly_id},
        })
```

there is no extradata ouput in the coords/polygon. now only coordinates like

```
POLYGON ((3102900.92 23355541.16, 3102900.900615673 23355541.220965....)
```

but the extradata is like

```
0.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question in case I forget how I did it and need to come back.

I created two lists one for the coords and the other for the data. Then i checked to make sure the polylines are closed and only keep those. Then i polygonize to coords and zip the two lists together and loop through the zipped lists and write them to my shapefile

```
coord_lst = []
extraData_lst = []

for line in polylines:
    if (line['geometry']['coordinates'][0] == line['geometry']['coordinates'][-1]):
        coords = line['geometry']['coordinates']
        extraData = line['properties']['extraData']
        coord_lst.append(coords)
        extraData_lst.append(extraData)
    else:
        pass

d = polygonize(coord_lst)
b = zip(d, extraData_lst)

coordlst = None
ndvi_lst = None
schema =  {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'extraData': 'float'}}
with fiona.open(outfc, 'w', crs=from_epsg(2278), driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema) as c:
    for i, j in b:
        c.write({
        'geometry': mapping(i),
        'properties': {'extraData':j},
        })
print ("finished")
```

This seems to has been a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the technologies you're using...

But:

1. shouldn't your schema include the "ExtraData" field in the properties object?
2. If the source has a ExtraData property, you should access that in your for loop and set it on the new polygon features.

what about-

```
schema =  {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'id': 'int', 'ExtraData': 'float'}}
with fiona.open(output_file, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as c:
    for poly_id,polygon in enumerate(polygonize(coords)):
        c.write({
            'geometry': mapping(polygon),
            'properties': {
                'id': poly_id,
                'ExtraData': polygon['properties']['ExtraData']
            },
        })
```

Comment: hmm, right, but it's not available in polygon anymore for whatever reason now only the coords are there POLYGON ((3102900.92 23355541.16, 3102900.900615673 23355541.220965....) so i need a way to get the extradata value back in there

Comment: Read and write from the same loop so you have access to the source feature and its original properties.

Comment: Mike can you give an example of that converting the linestring geometry to polygon geometry while keeping attributes in the same loop?

Comment: @Messak, is the source file a shapefile?

Comment: Yes, it is a shapefile

Comment: but it can be a geopandas df as well.